# How to exceed number of Shopify Variants more than 100

Tags: shopify, variants

I want to increase the number of variants more than 100, is there ant way to exceed this number of variants while Shopify offer 100 variants by default

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the shopify API will only allow 100. 
So, This requires a 3rd party application that can store the variant data in a separate database. There are several options available in the Shopify App Store, like this one: 
https://apps.shopify.com/product-customizer

Or, If any of your variants do not require separate inventory, you could use product line item property fields to store them. 
https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/features/get-customization-information-for-products

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a single product with up to 5000 variants fairly easily without external tools. Not sure how the page would perform though.

The trick is this. 
A collection can display up to 50 products at a time. Each of those products can have 100 variants so 5000 variants.

The collection gets a custom template that you set up to simulate a single product with lots of options.

This takes some skill beyond basic knowledge but doesn’t require an app at all.

Comment: _Striiiictly_ speaking, you can `{% paginate collection.products by 1000 %}` to get more than 50 products in your collection object with those 100 variants each.  The page load time absolutely tanks when you crank pagination up this high, granted, but the actual theoretical maximum would actually be (1000 * 100) = 1,000,000 if you used this method.

Comment: @user:2592369 1000 only works if you don't use a layout. While doable it raises a number of management issues but thanks for pointing that out. and FWIW 100* 1000 is 10^5 not 10^6 :-)

Comment: Eh. What's an order of magnitude between friends? But yes - apparently I can't count to 5 today.  And I've seen people use the 1000-product pagination on pages with normal layouts, though that was a few years ago when I was still in a support role.  Worked just fine, as long as you didn't mind a 5-minute delay for page loading :P

Answer (score 0):

Like Sophie mentioned there's a fair few plugins which can remove the [Shopify variant limit](https://katanamrp.com/blog/shopify-variant-limit) for you. That way you can have as many variants and options as you want for your products.

Just keep in mind that you won't be able to see these extra variants in the "Inventory" section of your store. You'll need some inventory management software to be able to track your stock efficiently in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Product Variants Reloaded app - https://apps.shopify.com/more-than-100-variants (upto 1000 variants per product). It works by bundling together variants from upto 10 products. Need to copy paste some code to the theme. It replaces the variant object with a combined variant object of 10 different products so works very smoothly on the site.